# Kendo UI Mobile custom font tabstrip color not applied

Tags: kendo-mobile

I've got a custom font so that I can have custom icons in the tabstrip.  When I use my font, the icon shows up but it's not using the color specified in the css.

It shows up black.  Even if I set the color directly in the debugger, no color is applied.

[image]

If I use the icon in a view, it shows up with correct color:

[image]

I assume there is some type of mask being applied but I can't figure out why it's making it black.  I figured at the very least, it would be the same color as the other native icons.

Note that if I change the color of all the icons (with the km-icon css class), my custom icons do not change.

Note also: When I debug, I see that css is telling me that the color should be orange:

[image]

css:

```css
.km-ios6 .km-tabstrip .km-icon.km-icon-trophies
{
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-bottom: -7px;
    color: orange !important;
}
```

html:

```html
    <div data-role="footer">
        <div data-role="tabstrip">
            <a href="#tabstrip-home" data-icon="home">Home</a>
            <a href="#tabstrip-journal" data-icon="icon-trophies">Journal</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems the font generator you're using is styling the ::before pseudo-element, while this element in Kendo UI Mobile's icons is used for shadows. You should style the ::after pseudo-element, like this:

```css
[class^="km-icon-"]:after, [class*=" km-icon-"]:after {
  font: 1em/1em "fishingfont";
  speak: none;

  text-decoration: inherit;
  width: 1em;
  margin-right: .2em;
  text-align: center;

  /* For safety - reset parent styles, that can break glyph codes*/
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;

  line-height: 36px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: .2em;
  font-size: 22px;
}
.km-icon-gear:after { content: '\61'; } /* 'a' */
.km-icon-fish:after { content: '\62'; } /* 'b' */
.km-icon-journal:after { content: '\63'; } /* 'c' */
.km-icon-hole:after { content: '\64'; } /* 'd' */
.km-icon-trophies:after { content: '\65'; } /* 'e' */

.km-ios6 .km-tabstrip .km-state-active .km-icon,
.km-content [class^="km-icon-"], .km-content [class*=" km-icon-"]
{
    color: orange;
}
```